# JAVAC Error with Path Change to jdk\bin

Tags: java

Problem still exists with Path Change to jdk67/bin.

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Dell>java -version
java version "1.7.0_67"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode, sharing)

C:\Users\Dell>javac
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Dell>echo %path%
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\Wind
owsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\ant194\bin;C:\maven323\bin;C:\Java\jdk67\bin;C:\Ruby200\b
in

C:\Users\Dell>javac
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Dell>

Please let me know.

Comment: I don't think anybody would *actually* call and answer your question. So please don't post *personal* data (email id / phone numbers) here.

Comment: You post the same question few minutes ago. Please use that if you still not clear

Comment: possible duplicate of [JAVAC Error - 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25929708/javac-error-javac-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: After setting the path. close and reopen cmd

Answer (score 0):

This may help you,

1.copy the  path upto 'bin' (Eg:-C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin)

2.Go to properties of 'MY COMPUTER'

3.Select 'Advanced System Settings'

4. Select 'Environment Variables'

5.Find 'Path' in 'System variables'

6.Click 'Edit'

7.Paste your above path into 'Variable value' By putting a semi-column(;)at the end of current 
values(Do not clear the value that already set)

8.click ok...ok

9.Go to Command Prompt and type 'javac' , if pathe setting is correct,it will show some information, if not correct it will show "javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Answer (score 0):

Probable JAVA Version 7 Update 67 Installation Problem - javac.exe not found

I think that there is no problem in giving contact numbers and this is not a same query

as it is on Windows 7.

After installing I tried to check javac.exe in this dir C:\Java\jdk67\bin and it was not

present there. Then I searched C:\ and culd not find there.

I installed JDK from the site:

https://java.com/en/download/index.jsp

I think that the installer has some problem.

Regards
Rohan Sarker
www.rohansarker.com
+913324288069 / +917278539338